# Django BinaryField default value

Tags: django

What can I use to set default value for BinaryField in Django? Every example, I've found just use

`field = models.BinaryField()`

and everything works somehow. What should I user for BinaryField(default=something)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use **django-binaryfield** ,example :

```
from binaryfield import BinaryField

class ExampleModel(models.Model):

    short_data = BinaryField(max_length=10, default=b'\x08')
    data = BinaryField()
```